# RowNum means in SQL and convert to SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I Have a SQL code which has rownum in it. as below:

```
 proc sql;
  create table dt as
 select d1.frst + (rownum - 1) as dt
                           from stg.stvcipc, work.d1                                        
                          where rownum  <=  d1.lst - (d1.frst - 1);quit;
```

d1.frst and d1.lst are date values. I don't know what is rownum means, what is trying to do. I need to change this code to SAS. Anything same with SAS?

```
        from sfrstcr r
                     , ssrmeet m
                     , ( select d1.frst + (rownum - 1)  dt
                           from saturn.stvcipc         -- about 1200
                              , ( select min(stvterm_start_date)  frst
                                       , max(stvterm_end_date)    lst
                                    from saturn.stvterm v
                                   where v.stvterm_fa_proc_yr                = '&v_aidy'                                          -- PARM '0910'
                                ) d1
                          where rownum  <=  d1.lst - (d1.frst - 1)
                       ) dt
```

This is the part of the original code. It is in select in select statements

Comment: That's already SAS code.  In that code, `rownum` is a variable in one of the contributing tables (not sure which, but likely `stg.stvcipc` given its use).

Comment: There is no variable as rownum in stg.stvcipc table or in work.d1.

Comment: Is that code not actually SAS code then, but rather code from SQL Server or something else that you've tossed into SAS?  Post it as it originally was, not as SAS code, if it's not SAS code.

Comment: I added the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Rownum is a pseudo column. It numbers the records in a result set. The first record that meets the where criteria in a select statement is given rownum=1, and every subsequent record meeting that same criteria increases rownum.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [reference](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/040-29.pdf), SAS proc SQL has a function called `monotonic()` that offers the same functionality.  I don't know if it can be called twice in one statement.  You can try the following:

```
proc sql;
  create table dt as
     select d1.frst + (monotonic() - 1) as dt
     from stg.stvcipc cross join work.d1                                        
     where monotonic() <=  d1.lst - (d1.frst - 1);
quit;
```

If this doesn't work, it is a little hard to say what to do without better understanding the intent of the code.

Comment: `monotonic()` is not exactly the same thing; it is an incremental function.  It does effectively the same thing, except that if it's used in a context where SQL might split things off into different parallel processes or otherwise not perform the query completely linearly, it won't reliably return what you expect.  It's different from `rownum` in SQL Server in that it's determined at a later point in execution.  SAS's official stance on `monotonic()` is that it is unsupported, undocumented, and not for production use.  In the general SAS community it's effectively a religious issue.